# List with a custom field and sort with a second custom field on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page where I list the items through a custom field called "country". This is my current code:

```
<?php

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array (
'posts_per_page' => 24,
'paged'          => $paged,
'category_name' => 'food', 
'meta_key'       => 'country',
'meta_value'     => 'Italy'
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while($custom_query->have_posts()) :
$custom_query->the_post();


..............



endwhile;
wp_reset_query ();
?>
```

Now I would like to add a second custom field called "order", numeric, which sorts the items listed with "country" through the new numeric custom field "order".

How can I do?

Thank you all

P.s. Sorry my bad English, but I'm Italian;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use WordPress meta query for passing multiple custom fields values inside it. You can use order by parameter. Please refer following example.

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'country_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'country',
        'value' => 'italy',
    ),
    'order_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'city',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ), 
),
'orderby' => 'order_clause', // Results will be ordered by 'city' meta values.
) );
```

Please try it.